# Delete around word in vim, taking leading space instead of space after word

Tags: vim

If I remove a word with `daw` in vim, it consumes one whitespace *after* that word as well.

If I want to add the word at the end of a sentence, how do I paste the word?

I often end up with a whitespace between the pasted word and the full stop, such as `hello.` becomes `hellopasted_word .` instead of `hello pasted_word.`.

So, the buffer `pasted_word<WHITESPACE>` should become `<WHITESPACE>pasted_word` before inserting.
Can I anyhow swap the trailing whitespace to a leading whitespace when necessary?

**Edit**

This is what I did:

`|x|` is the cursor position in normal mode.

`Hello, on|l|y you can help.`

Press `daw`.

`Hello, you can help.`

`Hello, you can hel|p|.`

Press `p`:

`Hello, you can helponly .`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my local vim (version 7.3). It works as expected without the whitespace. What version of vim are you using?

Comment: I am using 7.4 What does it mean "works as expected"? What result is expected to come up?

Comment: If you use `daw` in the space before the word, you get your desired result. ie, space before word is put in register. you can map this to a different custom mapping

Comment: Oh wow, I never noticed that! Thank you :-) Please write that as an answer.

Comment: What you describe in your edit is the expected behavior. The [definition of a word](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word) in vim is: `A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.`, thus the space *after* the word will be copied along, rather then before the word.

Comment: @Oldskool: So when I do `daw` in the space before a word, why does it take the space and the word after it to register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> ? It might not be appealing coz' it's feels non generic, but it works

Comment: Solves my problem, similar to @sudo bangbang's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`daw` deletes the word and whitespace after it

I think its better to use a special paste command to insert a space and then paste the text. This covers the problem of word in beginning of line and similar scenarios.

delete text using `diw`, use mapping for *special paste*

```
:nnoremap sp a<space><esc>p
```

or you do `daw` from the space before the word to be deleted, It deletes the space before the word along with it.

```
:nmap  dbs bhdaw
```

now `dbs` gives your required behaviour

Comment: to clarify: `d` for delete and `aw` is `a word`, see `:h aw`

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `viwohx`. Unlike `bh`, it'll also work on single letter words.

`viw` selects the current word, `o` move the cursor to the start of the selection, `h`, move left, and `x` cut as you already know.

Now the issue, is if your word in the first of the line. Right now I don't see any simple solution that doesn't require more complex things like the following mapping where I also prepend a space to the word cut.

```
:nnoremap <expr> bds col('.')==1 ? 'viwx:let @"=" ".@"'."\<cr>" : 'viwohx'
```

Answer (score 0):

`diw` deletes a word without the space after it

Comment: But without the space before either. This space becomes useful to paste back the word cut at the end of the sentence.